# How to change the parameter being sent using a Before Plugin?

Tags: magento2, plugin, before-plugin

I have a before Plugin that runs when a customer data is updated thru the admin. When "save customer" is clicked I need to update the values of some of the fields (like customerID)[image] the form before it gets saved in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an Observer may be the easier way, but if you want to use a plugin try

> /app/code/MagePal/CustomerSaveMod/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer">
        <plugin name="MagePal_CustomerSaveMod_before_customer_save" type="MagePal\CustomerSaveMod\Plugin\CustomerPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> /app/code/MagePal/CustomerSaveMod/Plugin/CustomerPlugin.php

```
namespace MagePal\CustomerSaveMod\Plugin;

class Order
{
    public function beforeSave(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer $subject,
        $object
    ) {
        //$object->setDob() 
        return [$object];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can suggest to you is to use the `customer_save_before` event

in your `Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_before">
        <observer name="change_customer_data_before_save" instance="Vendor/Module\Observer\UpdateCustomer"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

in your `Vendor/Module\Observer\UpdateCustomer.php` file

```
namespace Vendor/Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;

class UpdateCustomer implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        //you can change customer data here

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the info, but i need to use a plugin. is there a reason why a plugin wont work?